# swift how init value of model without model casting

Tags: swift

I have a Custom type:

```swift
struct Amount {
  var value: Double
}
```

And how to use like:

```swift
struct Car {
  var cost: Amount = 1.5 // 1.5 will be value of Amount
}
```

Comment: Consists ```Amount``` just of the attribute ```value```?

Comment: @finebel Sure. value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the use case of `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`:

```
struct Amount : ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
    typealias FloatLiteralType = Double
    
    init(floatLiteral value: Double) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    // optional, if you don't write this then you only get the floatLiteral: initialiser
    init(value: Double) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    var value: Double
}
```

And your `Car` will "magically" compile.

Note that this only works with literals like `1.5`, and not variables/constants such as:

```
struct Car {
    var cost: Amount = Constants.carCost // if carCost is a Double, this won't compile
}
```

Also, if you just want `Amount` to be another ***name*** for `Double`, and don't want it to be another different type, you can use a type alias:

```
typealias Amount = Double
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a typealias for `Double`:

```
typealias Amount = Double

struct Car {
  var cost: Amount = 1.5 // 1.5 will be value of Amount
}
```