# swift Custom data type cast to existing data type

Tags: swift

I have a custom data type:

```swift
struct Amount: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral, Codable {
    typealias FloatLiteralType = Double
    
    init(floatLiteral value: Double) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    init(value: Double) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    var value: Double
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(NSDecimalNumber(value: value).stringValue)
    }
}
```

And when I create model with it:

```swift
struct Car {
  var cost: Amount
}

var car = Car(cost: 1.5)
```

But when I set double typed value to model it not be inited:

```
var cost: Double = 1.5

var car = Car(cost: cost) // it won't be inited
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'Amount'

How to set double value to custom type?

Comment: You seem to be doing some custom encoding in `Amount`. Is that why you didn't use the `typealias` solution as I suggested in your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64726152/swift-how-init-value-of-model-without-model-casting)?

Comment: You have lots of options: `Car(cost: Amount(value: cost))`, or write a `init` for `Car` that takes a `Double` so you don't have to write `Amount` every time you create a `Car`, but I'm guessing you have some restrictions?

Comment: @Sweeper when encoding Double numbers sometimes it will be incorrect typed. Like 1.2 => 1.1999999999. And for fix it I created custom type

Comment: @Sweeper Im working with large project. And I search easiest way for refactoring just Double to Amount

Comment: In you example your are using a variable and not a literal value when calling the constructor and why not use Decimal instead of Double when dealing with fixed number of decimals

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialize your car with a Double but it expects an Amount. They are two different type even though they both conform to ExpressibleByFloatLiteral.

```
let cost: Amount = 1.5
let car = Car(cost: cost) // it works
```

Comment: I want to get double as amount)

Comment: I think you are going the wrong path I will post some links here.

Comment: IMO you should use Decimal and a custom encoder/decoder for it

Comment: If you need to initialize Car with a Double you need to provide an initializer that takes a Double as well as Amount.

Comment: Btw If you want to avoid the loss of precision when initializing your decimals you need to use the string initializer. ExpressibleByFloatLiteral will not solve your issue.

Comment: This is related to your issue as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/55131900/2303865